# Classroom.profiles.get returns 'User does not have permission'

Tags: google-apps-script, user-profile, google-classroom

I am trying to write a simple function to get all the students names and email addresses for a given class.  The students have a mixture of mydomain.ac.uk and gmail.com.  The students that have a `mydomain.ac.uk` address all return without problem, but if the student has a gmail account, I get the error 'The caller does not have permission'.

If I view the People tab of the course using the same superAdmin account that runs the code, I can see all of the students names and can email them.  How do I get my code to return the userProfile of these gmail account users?

```
var sEmail = Classroom.UserProfiles.get({'userId' : '111294713083730379429'}).emailAddress
```

If I can see this information in the Classroom, why can't I access the same information in my code?

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> If I can see this information in the Classroom, why can't I access the same information in my code?

Only Google can answer why. Please bear in mind that the user profile data for @gmail.com is stored on an external domain, gmail.com.

I suggest you to checkout the Google Classroom Issue Tracker if there is already an issue about this "feature".

Comment: I have looked through the Issue Tracker but it's not the easiest thing to navigate and couldn't find anything similar.  I find it difficult to believe that I'm the first to come across this issue!

Comment: Yes.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159152330  if you'd like to star it!